# Meaning of "closed" Path parameter in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapes

A basic question, but I haven't seen an answer on SO yet. The `closed` parameter when creating a `Path` object in the `matplotlib.path` library comes with the description: "If codes is None and closed is True, vertices will be treated as line segments of a closed polygon." I can't tell if this means you should type `closed=True` when instantiating a path with an already closed set of vertices, or if you should type closed=True when you want an open set of vertices to be closed for you.

Furthermore, [according to the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/path_api.html), the `contains_point()` and `contains_points()` functions "return whether the (closed) path contains the given point(s)."

Why does the function return the same thing regardless of whether or not provided vertices meet the requirement to be closed AND/OR have the "closed" parameter = True?

**Case 1: Vertices closed, closed parameter false by default**

```
In [2]: pth = path.Path([[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[0,0]])
In [3]: pth.contains_point([0.5,0.5])
Out[3]: True
```

**Case 2: Vertices closed, closed parameter true**

```
In [2]:  pth = path.Path([[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[0,0]],closed=True)
In [3]:  pth.contains_point([0.5,0.5])
Out[3]:  True
```

**Case 3: Vertices open, closed parameter false by default**

```
In [2]:  pth = path.Path([[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]])
In [3]:  pth.contains_point([0.5,0.5])
Out[3]:  True
```

**Case 4: Vertices open, closed parameter true**

```
In [2]:  pth = path.Path([[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]],closed=True)
In [3]:  pth.contains_point([0.5,0.5])
Out[3]:  True
```

Comment: The point choice is unfortunate because it lies on the line [0,0], [1,1]. Try [0.5, 0.7] instead. Even more confused? Then use `patch = PathPatch(pth, lw=3): ax.add_patch(patch)` to visualize what these paths actually create. I assume you have also seen this [Path tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/advanced/path_tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks @Mr. T, that does clarify some of my confusion. Though I wonder why the `closed` parameter in Case 4 turns the patch into a triangle? It seems to skip over the last vertex of [0,1].

Comment: I think (not sure, though, not much experience with path objects) that the last vertex is ignored in "closed=True". But maybe somebody else has more information on this subject.

Comment: it's clearly stated in the [documentation of the `closed` parameter](https://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html): **Note that the last vertex will then be ignored (as the corresponding code will be set to CLOSEPOLY).**

Comment: @Mr. T would you like to post your original comment as a formal answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sample conditions are reproduced by the following code, making clear why `contains_point([0.5,0.5])` always returned `True`. An unlucky coincidence of misunderstanding what the Path object considers as the inside of a path and where the test point was positioned:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 10))

point1 = [0.5, 0.5]
point2 = [0.3, 0.7]

titles = ["Case 1\nVertices closed, closed parameter false by default",
          "Case 2\nVertices closed, closed parameter true",
          "Case 3\nVertices open, closed parameter false by default",
          "Case 4\nVertices open, closed parameter true"]

paths = [Path([[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[0,0]],closed=True),
         Path([[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[0,0]]),
         Path([[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]]),
         Path([[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]],closed=True)]

for ax, t, p in zip(axes.flat, titles, paths):
    patch = patches.PathPatch(p, facecolor="orange", lw=2, zorder=0)
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    ax.scatter(*point1, label="Path contains point {}: {}".format(point1, p.contains_point(point1)))
    ax.scatter(*point2, label="Path contains point {}: {}".format(point2, p.contains_point(point2)))
    ax.set_title(t)
    ax.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Take-home messages:

- The area "enclosed" by a path is defined by the path vertices
  independent of whether the path is closed or not.
- As [Stef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3944322/stef) linked to in the
  comments, `closed=True` ignores the last vertex if no codes are
  provided: [If `codes` is `None` and `closed` is `True`, vertices will be
  treated as line segments of a closed polygon. Note that the last
  vertex will then be ignored (as the corresponding code will be set to
  `CLOSEPOLY`).](https://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html)